# Make basic genome sequence program work properly

Tags: python

I tried to create a program to check the genome sequence.

#### Context:

Biologists use a sequence of letters *A*, *C*, *T* and *G* to model a genome.
A gene is a substring of a genome that starts after a triplet *ATG* and ends before a triplet *TAG*, *TAA*, or *TGA*.
Furthermore, the length of a gene string is a multiple of 3 and the gene does not contain any of the triplets *ATG*, *TAG*, *TAA* and *TGA*.

#### My desired result is:

```
>>Enter a genome string:>>TTATGTTTTAAGGATGGGGCGTTAGTT
Output:
>>TTT
>>GGGCGT
>>Enter a genome string:>>TGTGTGTATAT
>>No gene is found
```

#### So far I have got:

```py
import re

def findGene(gene):
  pattern = re.compile(r'ATG((?:[ACTG]{3})*?)(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)')
  return pattern.findall(gene)

  findGene('TTATGTTTTAAGGATGGGGCGTTAGTT')

def main():
  geneinput = input("Enter a genome string: ")
  print(findGene(geneinput))


main()

# TTATGTTTTAAGGATGGGGCGTTAGTT
```

How can I make this code work properly?

Thank you.

Comment: What are examples of input and output that suggest this is not working correctly?

Comment: what exactly is not working?

Comment: Your code seems to work fine for me: https://repl.it/@HarunYlmaz/genome

Comment: yes, it is working but when I try to get output for 'TGTGTGTATAT' the output is always '[]' instead of 'No gene is found.' I want the program to give 'No gene is found' output if the gene sequence is incorrect.

Comment: One option: `print(findGene('TGTGTGTATAT') or 'No gene is found')`

Comment: @jarmod Thank you, I am able to find my desired code with your help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

def findGene(gene):
    pattern = re.compile(r'ATG((?:[ACTG]{3})*?)(?:TAG|TAA|TGA)')
    return pattern.findall(gene)

findGene('TTATGTTTTAAGGATGGGGCGTTAGTT')

def main():
    geneinput = input("Enter a genome string: ")
    print(findGene(geneinput) or 'No gene is found')


main()

# TTATGTTTTAAGGATGGGGCGTTAGTT
```

Comment: In case you need to be able to explain why this works, you need to understand the notion of 'truthy' and 'falsy' (sometimes spelled 'falsey'). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false